# Gatt disconnected during long response?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE device that sends me a long response - let's say 1000 frames/characteristics one after another.

What happens if the connection with BLE device breaks? Will it continue sending responses until all 1000 are send, or will it stop and go back to advertisement state?

Comment: that depends on the device software. Nobody except who created that device's firmware knows.

Comment: Uh, ok. Thank you :)

Comment: @Nocri, look at this [link](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/60/what-is-connection-parameters) about connection parameters - it might helpe